# The empty string '' is not a valid local name

Tags: c#, xml

trying to achieve this in xml document

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<pain.001.001.02>

..
</pain.001.001.02>
</Document>
```

used this code

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("BMW.xml"))
{
    string[] Color = new string[3] { "Red", "Black", "Blue" };
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Document");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("", "", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    ....
}
```

getting this error of "The empty string '' is not a valid local name".

so I tried below code but did not get the desired output I have mentioned, any support to get the desired output would be helpful.

```
  writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

and tried

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", null, "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02");
```

leads to different error of  **The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02' within the same start element tag.**

Comment: Well it's a fairly self explanatory error message and you are indeed trying to write an attribute using an empty string as a name, so what assistance are you expecting?

Comment: What do you currently understand about attribute names and namespaces? If you can share that, we'll be able to offer more specific help.

Comment: @CaiusJard will update the questions with all I did

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlWriter_WriteAttributeString_System_String_System_String_System_String_) for WriteAttributeString you'll see an example that is fairly helpful as it writes different attributes that are variations on what you're looking for:

```
 ...

 // Write the xmlns:bk="urn:book" namespace declaration.
 writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","bk", null,"urn:book");

 ...
```

Which would imply that to write an attribute of the form you're expecting you should supply a name for the namespace and attribute:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsl", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

I also doubt that the line above will write the data you want, as you seem to have put xsi in when you said you wanted xmlns to be output:

```
//doc says name can be null if prefix is xmlns (namespace declaration)
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", null, null, "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02");
```

Take a look at the example in MSDN, copy it and change the values as you need?

Comment: the code you have mentioned leads to The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02' within the same start element tag. error

Comment: There's a typo in the code that I've since corrected, but I would like to point out two things; one that your comment implies you still haven't read the manual (which would be an excellent start) and two, that answers on SO do sometimes have small typos; posting up a question doesn't absolve you of responsibility to think about the advice you're given nor does it make someone else responsible for doing all your work for you. It would be more reasonable and productive to fix the typo yourself, gain a better understanding of what is wrong and suggest an edit to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

instead of

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("", "", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

?

Relevant read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring?view=netframework-4.8

Hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: what would I want is to get the outcome as <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">